# Numpy subarrays with different and same shapes lead to np.asarray() error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, shapes

While trying to flip an numpy array I discovered the following problem:

When the arry consists of different shapes for each subarray np.flipud() works fine.

As soon as 2 or more subarrays have the same shape, but the shape of a third subarray differs, it throws a ValueError. The order of the subarrays doesn't matter in this case. While looking into the error I noticed that the same error already occurs when trying to convert the original python list into a numpy array.

```
import numpy as np

liste = []
liste.append(np.asarray([[1,2],[5,1],[4,5],[3,4],[3,4]]))
liste.append(np.asarray([[1,3,3,1],[1,3,3,1],[1,3,3,1],[1,3,3,1],[1,2,3,1]]))
liste.append(np.asarray([[1,3,3,1],[1,3,3,1],[1,3,3,1],[1,3,3,1],[1,2,3,1]]))
liste = np.asarray(liste)
liste = np.flipud(liste)

print(liste)
```

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5,2) into shape (5,)
```

How can I get around this issue?

Comment: It's making the array from that list that's the problem, and it is indeed the mix of shapes.

Comment: `flipud` just does `liste[::-1]`.  That works just as well on a list.

Comment: Interesting. `np.asarray` has different behavior when operating on a list of ndarrays, depending on the shapes of the ndarrays. With all the same shape, it concatenates them on a new first dimension like `np.stack`, but with different shapes, it either makes an array of dtype=object or raises a broadcasting error for reasons I can't quite follow.

Comment: That said, is `liste = [np.flipud(arr) for arr in liste]` what you're looking for?

Comment: @ElliotWay, that broadcast error arises when the subarrays have matching leading dimension(s).  It seems to have deduced that it can make array with that leading dimension.  See my answer for a work around that works for a 3 cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [15]: liste = []
    ...: liste.append(np.asarray([[1,2],[5,1],[4,5],[3,4],[3,4]]))
    ...: liste.append(np.asarray([[1,3,3,1],[1,3,3,1],[1,3,3,1],[1,3,3,1],[1,2,3,1]]))
    ...: liste.append(np.asarray([[1,3,3,1],[1,3,3,1],[1,3,3,1],[1,3,3,1],[1,2,3,1]]))
In [16]: liste
Out[16]: 
[array([[1, 2],
        [5, 1],
        [4, 5],
        [3, 4],
        [3, 4]]),
 array([[1, 3, 3, 1],
        [1, 3, 3, 1],
        [1, 3, 3, 1],
        [1, 3, 3, 1],
        [1, 2, 3, 1]]),
 array([[1, 3, 3, 1],
        [1, 3, 3, 1],
        [1, 3, 3, 1],
        [1, 3, 3, 1],
        [1, 2, 3, 1]])]
```

`np.array` can make an object dtype array from arrays that differ in shape, but if the arrays have a common initial shape, it runs into problems.  Making array from arrays that can differ in shape is inherently a fudge, an iffy task.

```
In [18]: np.array(liste,object)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-18-6790af79ec47>", line 1, in <module>
    np.array(liste,object)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5,2) into shape (5,)
```

A way around that is to crate an "blank" array of the right size, and then assign  the list to it. This also works if the subarrays are all the same size and you still want 1d object dtype array.

```
In [19]: arr = np.zeros(3, object)
In [20]: arr[:] = liste
In [21]: arr
Out[21]: 
array([array([[1, 2],
              [5, 1],
              [4, 5],
              [3, 4],
              [3, 4]]), array([[1, 3, 3, 1],
                               [1, 3, 3, 1],
                               [1, 3, 3, 1],
                               [1, 3, 3, 1],
                               [1, 2, 3, 1]]), array([[1, 3, 3, 1],
                                                      [1, 3, 3, 1],
                                                      [1, 3, 3, 1],
                                                      [1, 3, 3, 1],
                                                      [1, 2, 3, 1]])],
      dtype=object)
```

Then the flip does work

```
In [22]: np.flipud(arr)
Out[22]: 
array([array([[1, 3, 3, 1],
              [1, 3, 3, 1],
              [1, 3, 3, 1],
              [1, 3, 3, 1],
              [1, 2, 3, 1]]), array([[1, 3, 3, 1],
                                     [1, 3, 3, 1],
                                     [1, 3, 3, 1],
                                     [1, 3, 3, 1],
                                     [1, 2, 3, 1]]), array([[1, 2],
                                                            [5, 1],
                                                            [4, 5],
                                                            [3, 4],
                                                            [3, 4]])],
      dtype=object)
```

But it's just as easy to flip/reverse the list:

```
In [23]: liste[::-1]
Out[23]: 
[array([[1, 3, 3, 1],
        [1, 3, 3, 1],
        [1, 3, 3, 1],
        [1, 3, 3, 1],
        [1, 2, 3, 1]]),
 array([[1, 3, 3, 1],
        [1, 3, 3, 1],
        [1, 3, 3, 1],
        [1, 3, 3, 1],
        [1, 2, 3, 1]]),
 array([[1, 2],
        [5, 1],
        [4, 5],
        [3, 4],
        [3, 4]])]
```